# React Native: passing values between screen not working

Tags: react-native

I've two pages:
Page1: Two Variables CUR1:

```
render() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const cur1 = navigation.getParam('cur1', 'ABC');
```

Page2:

```
<Button badge rounded light style={styles.ok} onPress={() =>navigate('Home', {cur1:this.state.cur1})} >
  <Text style={styles.oks}>OK</Text>
</Button>
```

On double checking `this.state.cur1` is not empty, but after redirection to Page1 navigation.getParam shows default value

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to other screen by using following code

```
 <Button 
    title="button"
    onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2', {
                    letter: 'A'
    });}}
  />
```

Receive data in page 2 like below,

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
this.letter = params ? params.letter : null;
```

Comment: @DivyamSolanki i am using same code in my project its working fine. can you please share me entire code through online editor or github

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass through params , Below is the example.

```
navigate("Home",{},
  {
    type: "Navigate",
    routeName: "SecondView",
    params: {cur1:this.state.cur1
  }
```

Comment: You can find detail description about this issue in below link https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/143